# v-on:click inside the v-for is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a program in which i have to create multiple buttons and each button should perform different functionality on click.

I have used v-for for creating multiple buttons but the @click function is not called on click of the button. Can someone help me on this?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <div v-for="test in this.tests">
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="{{test.method}}">{{test.name}}<v-btm>
      </div>
      {{ c }}
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      a : 10,
      b : 5,
      c : 0,
      tests: [
        { name: "add", method:this.add()},
        { name: "subtract", method:this.subtract()}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    add(){
      this.c = this.a+this.b
    },
    subtract(){
      this.c = this.a-this.b
    }
  }
})
```

How to call the methods when the click event is triggered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```html
@click="{{test.method}}"
```

needs to be this:

```html
@click="test.method"
```

You don't need the braces. `{{ ... }}` is used to output text into the resulting HTML. Within a `v-bind` or `v-on` you just write the expression directly, without the `{{ ... }}`.

Then this:

```js
tests: [
  { name: "add", method:this.add()},
  { name: "subtract", method:this.subtract()}
]
```

needs to be this:

```js
tests: [
  { name: "add", method: this.add },
  { name: "subtract", method: this.subtract }
]
```

or alternatively:

```js
tests: [
  { name: "add", method: () => this.add() },
  { name: "subtract", method: () => this.subtract() }
]
```

The problem with the existing version is it will invoke `add` and `subtract` immediately, within the `data` function. The values for `method` will be set the the return values of those functions, which will be `undefined` in this case.

In my first suggestion I've just got rid of the `()`, so they won't be invoked immediately. Instead a reference to the functions will be assigned to `method`. Vue automatically binds `this`, so there's no risk of the `this` being dropped.

In the second variation I've wrapped them in arrow functions. Again this avoids the problem of invoking them immediately. In this scenario there's no real need to wrap them but it can be more flexible in general. A little care has to be taken to ensure a correct `this` value, this wouldn't have worked if I'd used normal functions instead of arrow functions.